solution-verification | show that $[BN$ is the bisector of the angle $\angle VBC$
The problem
Let $VABCD$ be a regular quadrilateral pyramid with peak $V$. The plane $\alpha$ contains the line $AB$ and cuts $CV$ and $DV$ at the point $M$, respectively $N$. If $P$ is the midpoint of CN and $MP \perp CN $, show that $[BN$ is the bisector of the angle $\angle VBC$.
my idea
drawing


We know that $AB|| (VDC), \alpha \cap (VDC) =MN$ and that $MN \in \alpha$ which means that $MN || AB|| DC$ and by thales we get that $MC=ND=x$, $VM=NV=y$
Also, we know that $MP \perp NC$, and that also $MP$ is a median in triangle MNC which makes it an isosceles triangle with $MN=MC=x$
$VB=VC=VM+MC=x+y$
by the theorem of similarity applied in triangle $VDC$, we get that $\ \frac {y}{x+y}=\frac{x}{DC}=> DC=\frac{x(x+y)}{y}$
From all of this calculus, we can conclude that $\frac{VM}{MC}= \frac{VB}{BC}=\frac{y}{x}$ which by the reciprocal of the theorem of the bisector we get that BM is the bisector of $\angle VBC$
I know that the problem says that we have to show that $BN$ is the bisector of that angle, but I don't think that is correct, that's I put this as a solution verification.
Also, I'm not sure if this part is right: ,,We know that $AB|| (VDC), \alpha \cap (VDC) =MN$ and that $MN \in \alpha$ which means that $MN || AB|| DC$"
I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Drawing are sometimes hard to see/read; You might want to consider using GeoGebra.

Your proof looks fine.

@Intelligentipauca So BN can't be the bisector of $\angle VBC$?

Of course it can't: $N$ doesn't lie on plane $VBC$.
